# Using a scanner-method for multiple set methods within class

Tags: java, class, methods

I am trying to create scanner methods within my class `Address` so I do not have to repeat the scanner code in every single method where I want user input. What I'm having problem with is that this method only seems to return my instance variable values and not the scanner inputs from the user when I run these two set methods in a test program of an instance of my `Address` class.

How can I do this? I do not want to repeat the `scr.nextInt()` etc in every single method.

```html
    
//Scanner method for integer inputs from user.
public int scanInt(){
    int userInt = scr.nextInt();
    scr.nextLine();
    return userInt;
}

//Scanner method for string inputs from user
public String scanLine(){
    String userString = scr.nextLine();
    return userString;
}
 
//in these methods below (and others) I want to use the above scanner methods so I don't have to repeat the code for scanner inputs in every single method.

public void setStreet(){
    System.out.println("Skriv in gata: ");
    scanLine();
}

public void setStreetNr(){
    System.out.println("Skriv in gatunummer: ");
    scanInt();
}
```

Comment: Your methods return an int and String object but you're not assigning them to any variables.

Comment: Please elaborate on exactly what you want. A way of doing this would be running the program, showing the output, and letting us know what output you *want*.

Comment: I want to be able to run an instance of this class in a test program for example and use these two methods for setting street and streetNr and then return the values that the user inputs via the scanner. I hope I'm making sense, I'm not exactly a pro in java after about 3 weeks ;).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setStreet(){
    System.out.println("Skriv in gata: ");
    street = scanLine();
}
```

Comment: Emile, you're a star. can't believe I didn't think of this simple solution ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are testing your class with BlueJ or some other program.  If that's the case, try this class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Address
{
    String street;
    int streetNr;
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Scanner method for integer inputs from user.
    public int scanInt()
    {
        int userInt = scr.nextInt();
        scr.nextLine();
        return userInt;
    }

    //Scanner method for string inputs from user
    public String scanLine()
    {
        String userString = scr.nextLine();
        return userString;
    }

    public void setStreet()
    {
        System.out.println("Skriv in gata: ");
        street = scanLine();
    }

    public void setStreetNr()
    {
        System.out.println("Skriv in gatunummer: ");
        streetNr = scanInt();
    }
}
```

This should work as you describe.  Create an instance of the class, call both methods and inspect your object's parameters.  This code assigns your inputs to a variable for each method.

Comment: thank you for your answer Zobris. this is the solution that Emile helped me come up with.